# Application built on reactive WebClient is getting crashed in PROD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have developed one service using spring boot 2.x and reactive webclient.
Due to some business requirement I had to block the webClient call.
During performance testing I observe that CPU usage is going beyond 100% and application is getting crashed, I really appreciate your support to fix this issue.

I tried excluded Netty dependency and tried with Jetty but it doesn't help me out. Eventually I used basic configuration for httpClient and webclient from Netty as below.

```java
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
.tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, connectionTimeout)
.doOnConnected(connection -> connection.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(readTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))).proxy(proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).host(proxyHost).port(proxyPort)));


ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);


WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build()
```

Comment: and it would kill you to post the crash log here?

Comment: pls, dont post it here, update your question with the logs

Comment: and you posted the crash log, i want to see the application log until the crash